# Rails routes appear but throws a 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to thrown a 404 error without redirect for unknown routes. It works correctly but when I go to the show routes, that it is in the rails routes, it throws a 404 too.

Relevant section from routes.rb

```
      get '(/:department)',                     to: 'products#index'           
      get 'saldao',                             to: 'products#on_sale',              as: :on_sale
       
      get '*missing',                           to: 'error#error_404',               as: :error_404
      
      get '(:department)(/:brand)(/:os)',       to: 'products#index',                as: :products   
      get '(:department)(/:brand)(/:os)/:slug', to: 'products#show',                 as: :product
```

It`s weird because Product#show appears in the routes when i check:

```
products GET        (/:scope)(/:department)(/:brand)(/:os)(.:format)                                    frontend/products#index {:scope=>/pre|loyalty|corporativo|diaconsumidor|troca4g|troca3g4g|outlet|j4|z3|j6/, :department=>/celulares|acessorios|pos|controle|wttx/, :brand=>/alcatel|apple|asus|lenovo|lg|motorola|nokia|philips|positivo|samsung|sony|tim|wnc/, :os=>/android|ios|windows-phone/}
```

I've tried a lot of things and haven`t been succesfull.

The error route also stops work with I move it to the end of file.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, can you specify what is not working, e.g. what you expected and how the result you had differed from your expectations? I don't wee any issue here with the current form of the question.

Comment: Hi, thank you! When I click in the product I want to, instead of show the objetc, I see a 404 not found page. It's like the route to show was unknown

Comment: Check that the URL of your link is correct

Comment: It's correct! It works fine when i remove the line `get '*missing',  to: 'error#error_404',               as: :error_404`

Comment: check https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages and see if it can help

Comment: Yeah, it works. The problem is that I dont want the url to change to example.com/404.
If I type example.com/abc and the page doesn't exist, I wanna see the page error but the url need to still be example.com/abc

Comment: with the above solution it doesn't redirect you to /404 (even if it looks like it does)

Comment: weird, i tried that and it's redirecting